# Magento 2 : subcategories in category menu

Tags: category, magento-2.1, sidebar

Iam using this extension for displaying left menu category sidebar https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar. For main categories its working fine , i enabled flat category as well but its not showing sub categories .this function returns empty array        $childCategories = $this->getSubcategories($category);

```
   public function getChildCategoryView($category, $html = '', $level = 1)
{
    // Check if category has children
    if ( $category->hasChildren() )
    {

        $childCategories = $this->getSubcategories($category);

        if ( count($childCategories) > 0 )
        {

            $html .= '<ul class="o-list o-list--unstyled">';

            // Loop through children categories
            foreach ( $childCategories as $childCategory )
            {

                $html .= '<li class="level' . $level . ($this->isActive($childCategory) ? ' active' : '') . '">';
                $html .= '<a href="' . $this->getCategoryUrl($childCategory) . '" title="' . $childCategory->getName() . '" class="' . ($this->isActive($childCategory) ? 'is-active' : '') . '">' . $childCategory->getName() . '</a>';

                if ( $childCategory->hasChildren() )
                {
                    if ( $this->isActive($childCategory) )
                    {
                        $html .= '<span class="expanded"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></span>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $html .= '<span class="expand"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>';
                    }
                }

                if ( $childCategory->hasChildren() )
                {
                    $html .= $this->getChildCategoryView($childCategory, '', ($level + 1));
                }

                $html .= '</li>';
            }
            $html .= '</ul>';
        }
    }

    return $html;
}

/**
 * Retrieve subcategories
 *
 * @param $category
 *
 * @return array
 */

      public function getSubcategories($category)
{
    if ( $this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() &&   $category->getUseFlatResource() )
    {
        return (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
    }

    return $category->getChildren();
}
```

can anyone help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to just create block and inside template file call function,

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class Customcategory extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    protected $categoryFactory;
    protected $_catalogLayer;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,    
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,     
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory; 
        $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();        
        $this->storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $postDataHelper,
            $layerResolver,
            $categoryRepository,
            $urlHelper,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getCurrentCategoryData(){
        $categories = $this->_catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
        return $categories;
    }

    public function getCategoryData($id){
        return $category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($id);       
    }
}
```

Inside phtml file,

```
<?php
    $currentCategory = $this->getCurrentCategoryData();
?>
<?php
    foreach($currentCategory as $categoryDetails){
        $categoryId = $categoryDetails->getId();

        $categoryObj = $this->getCategoryData($categoryId);   
        $categoryName = $categoryObj->getName();
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is mistake in above code

Comment: Hi  @Rakesh its woking fine but in category list page its not showing main categories